# "So" as a semi-causal linker

Tags: filler

There is a clearly causal use of "so", as: "It's cold so I'm putting my coat on." But "so" is used also in what appears to be a filler role, but isn't really a filler in the normal sense, like "um". I'm trying to find a paper (or some clear explanation, anyway) about what I'm calling the "semi-causal" use of "so". Here's an example of real transcribed text that exemplifies what I'm trying to tease out:

"...And then BM is congruent to CM. So[1], BM is congruent to CM. Let's see what we got here. So[2], that is definition of bisecting a line segment. So[3], you're gonna get those two perpendicular lines, I think, cause look like that to me. So[4], definition of bisecting a line segment. Oh, well hold on, perpendicular has nothing to do with that, but yeah, still bisecting. I think you're gonna get congruence there, so[5]."

Here "so" is used several times, which I've numbered (the [numbers] aren't part of the transcript, in case that's not obvious. I just added them! :-) You're going to want to hear it, but I obviously can't do that, so you'll have to take my word a bit for the interpretation here, but it's pretty clear (at least when you hear it) that So[3] is causal and So[4] is a filler. But So[2] is interesting...it's the sort of thing I'm looking for an name for where it's saying something semi-causal, like: "Given all the above..." or "Given my current state of knowledge...". It's not filler, but it's not indicating content causality -- more like context causality, or something. It turns out in this that So[5], even though the subject never finishes the thought, when you hear it sounds like this sort of "so" as well, like they're thinking about the state of play of their problem solving, not just "um"'ing. (Come to think of it, maybe "um"ing  sometimes serves this role as well! "Like" definitely does, but in a different sense -- it's not causal so much as expressing an abstract comparative.)

Thanks in advance for any help on this you can offer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I found an answer to this...or at least one version of an answer, from D. Schiffran's (1987) "Discourse Markers". Schiffrin argues that in these cases "so" marks causal relations at a more "global level of discourse" (p. 203). In other words, the second use of "so" does not mark a direct cause—effect relation, but it may mark a global causal connection between the next event and all of the events that have led up to it in the narrative.